# SQL - Count dates that a status was held in a date range

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to determine the number of dates, in a date range, that a person held a particular status. I have three tables with the following (simplified) structure:

```
Table             Fields
 Calendar          Date
 DateRange         RangeID, StartDate, EndDate
 StatusHistory     PersonID, Status, Date
```

The Calendar table contains the list of dates that I want to consider for the count. A person's status change may have been recorded before, after, or in the middle of the range, or might switch between statuses several times within that range.

I'd like to:

```
select PersonID, RangeID, Status, count(*) as DateCount
```

or at least have a result set with that structure.

I'm using SQL on DB2 for IBM i.

**Edit** with sample data:

DateRange table (containing the ranges I'd like to consider)

```
 RangeID  StartDate    EndDate
+--------+------------+------------+
| A      | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-31 |
| B      | 2015-02-06 | 2015-03-05 |
| C      | 2015-03-07 | 2015-04-30 |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

Calendar table (containing the dates I'd like to count)

```
 Date            RangeID (not in Calendar table, but shown here for clarity)
+------------+   ----
| 2015-01-05 |
| 2015-01-06 |    A
| 2015-01-07 |
| 2015-01-08 |
                 ----
| 2015-02-05 |
                 ----
| 2015-02-06 |
| 2015-02-07 |    B
| 2015-02-08 |
| 2015-03-05 |
                 ----
| 2015-03-06 |
                 ---- 
| 2015-03-07 |
| 2015-03-08 |
| 2015-04-05 |    C
| 2015-04-06 |
| 2015-04-07 |
| 2015-04-08 |
+------------+   ----
```

StatusHistory table (containing the dates that a person's status was entered or changed)

```
 PersonID Status  Date
+--------+-------+------------+      Edit for clarification:
| 1      | HAPPY | 2015-01-05 |      While there's only one date  
| 1      | SAD   | 2015-02-07 |      in each of these records, 
| 1      | HAPPY | 2015-04-06 |      a date range is implied. That is,
| 2      | HAPPY | 2015-01-07 |      Person 1 is HAPPY from 2015-01-05
| 3      | SAD   | 2014-10-31 |      to 2015-02-07, then SAD 'til
| 3      | SAD   | 2015-01-07 |      2015-04-06 and HAPPY from then on.
| 3      | HAPPY | 2015-04-05 |
| 3      | SAD   | 2015-04-06 |
| 3      | SAD   | 2015-04-07 |
+--------+-------+------------+
```

Result set

```
 PersonID RangeID Status  DateCount
+--------+-------+-------+---------+
| 1      | A     | HAPPY | 4       |
| 1      | B     | HAPPY | 1       |
| 1      | B     | SAD   | 3       |
| 1      | C     | HAPPY | 3       |
| 1      | C     | SAD   | 3       |
| 2      | A     | HAPPY | 2       |
| 2      | B     | HAPPY | 4       |
| 2      | C     | HAPPY | 6       |
| 3      | A     | SAD   | 4       |
| 3      | B     | SAD   | 4       |
| 3      | C     | HAPPY | 1       |
| 3      | C     | SAD   | 5       |
+--------+-------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Supplying sample data and desired results would help us better understand the question.  As is, it's difficult to guess as to what you're looking for.

Comment: I was worried the sample data might make the question really long. It looks like I was right about that, but I hope it helps.

Comment: ...The `StatusHistory` table is an exclusive upper-bound, but it's not clear if the `DateRange` table is as well (it _should_ be, if it isn't)...

Comment: I disagree, have you ever worked for huge exhibitions? The end date is usually included if you say exhibition X goes from date A to date B (never saw B excluded). I would agree for TimeStamps or DateTime, but not for Date (it should be treated as Date then and not DateTime what many databases are not doing unfortunately).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'd have an easier time of this if you were on LUW, and had access to `LEAD` (window functions are nice), but we'll just have to emulate it.

The first thing you need to ask is a conceptual question: what are you trying to count?  The answer is "days" - yes, you have conditions, but that's what you're trying to count.  So your initial table (the one in the `FROM`) will actually be your calendar table.

The next thing we'll need to do is to get the start-of-next range for `StatusHistory` (note that this would be an exclusive-upper bound.  Always query dates/times/timestamps with an exclusive upper-bound... in fact, it's better if you pretend [`BETWEEN` does not exist](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)).  Not having `LEAD` on the i, we'll have to emulate it.  First, we need to index the entries, starting over for each person, and ordered by their entries:

```
StatusHistoryIndex (personId, status, startDate, index) 
                AS (SELECT personId, status, startDate,
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY personId ORDER BY startDate) 
                    FROM StatusHistory)
```

... next, we need to use this to connect the "current" row with the "next" one, by the generated index:

```
StatusHistoryRange (personId, status, startDate, endDate)
                AS (SELECT Curr.personId, Curr.status, Curr.startDate,
                           Nxt.startDate
                    FROM StatusHistoryIndex Curr
                    LEFT JOIN StatusHistoryIndex Nxt
                           ON Nxt.personId = Curr.personId
                              AND Nxt.index = Curr.index + 1)
```

.... because we have an open upper-bound - we run up until the "last possible entry", and we don't *have* a "last" entry - we need to `LEFT JOIN` for `Nxt` (next), and the ending date (important - start of the next status!) will be null for the last entry.  This sort of logic is a prime candidate to wrap in a view (to give the appearance of a complete range table), and potentially building an MQT if performance is an issue.

From here, it's straightforward.  We don't have to worry about duplicates - the way we'll be joining takes care of that - and the ranges will overlap automatically as well.

A quick demonstration:
Given a calendar table that looks like this -

```
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
2015-01-04
2015-01-05
```

... and a range table like this -

```
2015-01-02   2015-01-05
```

... Then joining can only *restrict* the rows chosen, as if it were a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT date
FROM Calendar
JOIN Range
  ON Calendar.date >= Range.start
     AND Calendar.date < Range.end
```

would yield:

```
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
2015-01-04
```

Of the excluded rows, `2015-01-01` is ignored because it's less than the start of the range, and `2015-01-05` is ignored because it's greater-than/equal to the end of the range.  Joining more times with additional, similar ranges can only further restrict the data chosen.  We have all the pieces we need.

The full statement ends up looking like this:

```
WITH StatusHistoryIndex (personId, status, startDate, index) 
                     AS (SELECT personId, status, startDate,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY personId ORDER BY startDate) 
                     FROM StatusHistory),
     StatusHistoryRange (personId, status, startDate, endDate)
                     AS (SELECT Curr.personId, Curr.status, Curr.startDate,
                                Nxt.startDate
                         FROM StatusHistoryIndex Curr
                         LEFT JOIN StatusHistoryIndex Nxt
                                ON Nxt.personId = Curr.personId
                                   AND Nxt.index = Curr.index + 1)
                     
SELECT SHR.personId, DateRange.id, SHR.status, COUNT(*)
FROM Calendar
JOIN DateRange
  ON Calendar.calendarDate >= DateRange.startRange
     AND Calendar.calendarDate < DateRange.endRange
JOIN StatusHistoryRange SHR
  ON Calendar.calendarDate >= SHR.startDate
     AND (Calendar.calendarDate < SHR.endDate OR SHR.endDate IS NULL)
GROUP BY SHR.personId, DateRange.id, SHR.status
ORDER BY SHR.personId, DateRange.id, SHR.status
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e8020/9/0)</kbd>
(please note that my numbers are rather different than your example result.  I'm confident the numbers I'm getting are the correct result, given the starting data, but let me know if I missed something)

You didn't specify, but I treated the ending date in `DateRange` as an exclusive upper-bound, which you may need to adjust (you *should* be storing the exclusive upper-bound here).
I also didn't put a limit on the ending date for the status.  Presumably this would be `CURRENT_DATE`, although none of your test data went that far.  It would be possible to put `COALESCE(Nxt.startDate, CURRENT_DATE)` inside the range CTE, but this is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: The results are not very different, but they differ by 1 (because I don't see how there can be a mistake in my 2nd query I guess there is one in yours), you just get higher counts because you make a calendar entry for each day.

Comment: `AND Calendar.calendarDate < DateRange.endRange` ... this is probably the reason, it should be `<=`. PS: Seems to be true, just tested.

Comment: @maraca - date/time/timestamp values (well, just timestamps really, but at least one of those dates could be promoted to one) are all positive, contiguous-range types (not an explicit integer count).  That is, you can always define a more accurate value.  Because it's positive - and how numbers are represented - the correct way to deal with them is an exclusive upper-bound (`<`).  If it's negative, flip which bound is exclusive.  (Zero is a special case either way).  Otherwise you have potential problems with missing or duplicated values.

Comment: @maraca - Some of this is because I was assuming a `Calendar` table had an entry for every date (which is the usual use, I think).

Comment: @ Yes, you can argue that it makes sense to exclude the upper bound, but what he is doing here is storing an entry in calendar for each work day (no saturday and sunday probably). Otherwise this whole calendar table would be just useless.

Comment: @maraca - oh, no, a Calendar table is **much** more useful if you have every date in it.  With a lot of additional columns, and a bunch of indices (year/month/day, day-of-week, fiscal period, whatever).  It makes certain types of analysis queries _extremely_ easy and performant (because now you can use an index from a range for grouping by week, say, instead of trying to call a function for every entry, which would invalidate the use of indices).

Comment: ... **if** you have additional columns, I don't see any, why would he need to join the calendar if there was an entry for each day just to count? Doesn't make sense. You are always talking about hypothetical stuff and not about the question.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've found myself in Kanab, Utah for the weekend, so I haven't been able to test it out. I'll let you know if I can use it.

Comment: @maraca - There aren't any extra columns in my sample data; yes, I'm talking about a hypothetical one.  Having an entry for each date _is_ the point.  It's roughly equivalent to what you're doing with the Cartesian join.  It makes it **really easy** to do certain types of queries.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse This gives me the results I'm looking for, with one small change: including the end date from the date range in the join (i.e. Calendar.calendarDate <= DateRange.endRange). Is that an acceptable modification?

Comment: @Kendall - That should work, yes, if your end bound is inclusive.  Note that it would be better to change to using an exclusive upper bound (update `DateRange.endRange`), although this may be difficult if many existing process rely on it.  Also note that the status table is using an exclusive bound by definition (since presumably you can't have two statuses at the same time), so you have different types of ranges...

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions:

1. Calculate all combinations and count them, so that 0s are displayed
2. Only show combinations with count > 0 by grouping

The idea to get the correct status is to join with StatusHistory on the date where it is <= the calendar date, but there exists no date bigger than the one from the status with the same PersonID and <= the calendar date. So essentially this trick selects the last existing state for a person (if any) on the given calendar day.

**Version 1**: Tested on PostgreSQL and Oracle ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b30d6/6/0)).

```
SELECT
   p.PersonID,
   r.RangeID,
   s.Status,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Calendar c WHERE c.Date_ BETWEEN r.StartDate AND r.EndDate AND
      EXISTS(SELECT * FROM StatusHistory h WHERE
         h.PersonID = p.PersonID AND h.Status = s.Status AND h.Date_ <= c.Date_ AND
         NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM StatusHistory z WHERE
            z.PersonID = p.PersonID AND z.Date_ <= c.Date_ AND z.Date_ > h.Date_))
   ) AS Amount
FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT PersonID FROM StatusHistory) p,
   (SELECT RangeID, StartDate, EndDate FROM DateRange) r,
   (SELECT DISTINCT Status FROM StatusHistory) s
;
```

**Version 2**: Alternatively you can modify the old solution if you don't want the 0s ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b30d6/11/0)):

```
SELECT
   h.PersonID,
   r.RangeID,
   h.Status,
   COUNT(*)
FROM
   Calendar c,
   DateRange r,
   StatusHistory h
WHERE
   c.Date_ BETWEEN r.StartDate AND r.EndDate AND
   h.Date_ <= c.Date_ AND
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT s.Date_ FROM StatusHistory s WHERE
      s.Date_ <= c.Date_ AND s.Date_ > h.Date_ AND s.PersonID = h.PersonID)
GROUP BY
   h.PersonID,
   r.RangeID,
   h.Status
;
```

If you make the first query `MINUS` the second query you will see that indeed only the rows with count = 0 are returned as it should be, because other than the 0 counts the queries should return the same rows.

The select was already correct, all that was needed is the grouping and correctly join / filter the tables. The grouping is needed because count is an aggregate function (like sum, min, max etc.) and they work on groups. You can imagine that you only look at the columns specified in group by and where they are the same they are put in one group, for the other columns you have to use aggregate functions (you cannot store several rows in one cell except if you use group_concat (mysql) or listagg (oracle) which are also aggregate functions).

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat this information of him was added later, I always give detailed responses to detailed questions, because like it was it looked like one that is going to just accept the first working version (if any at all) without the will to learn anything.

Comment: It's not like that. I was just trying to be concise, and I appreciate you taking the time to respond. However, your answer doesn't seem to take in to account the Calendar table, which contains that dates that are to be counted, so it's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Kendall no problem it just looked like that before the update, I also prefer concise questions, if it is too long I might not even read it unless the things shown clearly help to clarify the situation and are not just trash. *To your problem*: have you tried the query? It should work correctly, you don't need to join the calendar because there is one entry per date per person in the history table, or is your problem that you want have the count of any person in any period (also for those with no entry of the person in that period)?

Comment: Perhaps I could have been more clear. StatusHistory is meant to indicate that Person 1 was HAPPY from 2015-01-05 to 2015-02-07, from there SAD 'til 2015-04-06, and HAPPY from then on. So there is an implied range of dates, but the table only includes the updated status and the date it was changed.

Comment: @Kendall I understood it now, maybe the new solution works for you, I might have misunderstood and you don't need the 0's then there is surely a more elegant way by grouping.

Comment: @Kendall I've given you two solutions now, it's still not 100% clear because you haven't defined what happens if there is no statushistory entry (take default value or ignore) and what happens if there is no status for the first days in a date range (do you take the the last status from the previous range as here or do you just ignore those days...).

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat as I thought, now the perfect answer even with the verification through `MINUS`, will anything happen here... probably not, and I'm still the only person who upvoted the question.

Comment: ...ouch.  First, I don't feel there's any sort of reasonable conceptual 0 for this dataset, or it ends up being too much noise.  Second, that first solution is going to kill the db - you're doing a Cartesian product in the outer query for a **lot** of additional rows, then you're doing a triple nested subquery in the `SELECT` (which in some cases may be run _for each row_...).  Your second query seems to work, but the conditions for the join to `StatusHistory` are a bit opaque.  And please, start explicitly qualifying your joins, and stop using the comma-separated `FROM` clause.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse 1st the reason why you want to have all combinations is to make excel exports or to use the query in reporting software etc. 2nd I don't see performance mentioned in the question 3rd my version 2 is fine from that perspective 4th if you use the join or put it in where is not such a big deal, i always use join on if i can say a=b and b=c... I don't want to put an exists or something in the join on. 5th What were you trying to say? 6th I don't believe anything until I've measured it on real data. 7th why even bother?

Comment: Oh, I'm well aware of what you _can_ use it for (been there, done that), I'm just not sure it's answering a useful question in this case.  The problem with implicit joins is it may be difficult to tell whether a condition was dropped or not.  If you want the Cartesian product, use `CROSS JOIN` instead.  Sticking stuff in the `WHERE` can also make `OUTER JOIN`s (usually `LEFT`) behave funny.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I say sticking stuff in joins makes them behave funny, that with the where will result in the same if done correctly. Actually I've seen a lot of mistakes when they put stuff in join, but part of it should have been in the where... It's also about readability and I prefer my 2nd version to the one with joins. I never had any problem with any of my queries btw. if you put other stuff than a.id = b.id and a.id = c.id in your join your data design is probably bad, just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've found myself in Kanab, Utah for the weekend, so I haven't been able to test it out. I'll let you know if I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

While you normally join with equality, it's not required.

In you case, you'll want to use BETWEEN

```
select PersonID, RangeID, Status, count(*) as DateCount
from Calendar c
     join DateRange d on c.date between d.StartDate and d.EndDate
     join StatusHistory s on s.date between d.StartDate and d.EndDate
group by s.PersonID, d.RangeID, s.Status
```

Should give you what you want..

Comment: This will not work because there isn't an entry for status history for each day and person.

Comment: And it would count too high because you join with all states in range and not just the one for the calendar day.